# call function from js file in html file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have one html file. In that file on click of button I want to call a function which is in a js file. How to do that?

Here is my html file as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Scrollable HTML table plugin for jQuery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Mobile: Demos and Documentation</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../docsdemos-style-override.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>


</head>
<body  >

<!-- main login page -->
<div id="mypage" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">


    <div data-role="header" align="center">
        <img border="0" src="../jquery.mobile/images/toplogo.png" />

    </div>


    <div data-role="content">

        <form id="loginForm" >
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br" >
                <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
                    name="username" id="username" value="" /> <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" /> <label
                    for="dob">Date of birth:</label> <input type="password"
                    type="password" name="dob" id="dob" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-a" >
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a" data-theme="a" >
                    <div class="ui-block-a" data-theme="a">
                        <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Login"
                            id="submitButton">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" data-theme="a">
                        <input type="reset" data-role="button" value="Cancel"
                            id="cancelButton"> 
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>


<!-- main menu -->


<script>

    console.log("clickkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
    $("#loginForm").on("submit",handleLogin);


</script>
```

This html file is in www/UI folder. Now there is below js file name as main.js which is in www/js folder. which contains  handleLogin function.

```
function handleLogin()
{

 }
```

How to call this function from my html file. Because when I click on login button same page is get called. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same page is called because it's submitting the form. You need to cancel this behaviour.

```
function handleLogin(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    //do stuff here...
}
```

Note the `evt` argument. This is automatically forwarded to any event callback - it is the event object, which contains data about the fired event, and which must be referenced in order to cancel the form's default action.

**However** it would be better to bind to the form's submit event rather than directly to the button, in case the user submits the form via the enter key. To do this, change your jQuery to

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit', handleLogin);
```

Comment: Hi Utkanos I had added evt in js file as you suggest above and call $('#loginForm').on('submit', handleLogin); from login.html still same page getting displayed. Thanks

Comment: Provided you're sure your `handleLogin` function is getting called (check this) and there's no JS errors, this should not happen. If stil unsure, set up a JS Fiddle to show us.

Comment: I did say *check the console* for errors. There are indeed errors. `handleLogin` is not accessible by your jQuery code. This is because that code is loading before the script that includes your function - therefore, when your jQ tries to bind to `handleLogin`, that function doesn't exist yet. Your jQ shouldn't be in your HTML, anyway - move it to the same file as your function.

Comment: @ Utkanos will you please  show me Fiddle because after adding handleLogin in html also doesn't show me alert [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nT3hg/61/)

Comment: OK, the plot thickens... it's failing because you're using jQuery's `on` method, but the version of jQuery you're using in the Fiddle is 1.5 (`on()` arrived in 1.6). Change to a higher version of jQuery and your latest Fiddle is fine. You stil shouldn't have your JS in your HTML, though, and you still shouldn't have opening braces (`{`) on different lines. After all this, you might wish to up-vote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

the code should work if the `main.js` is loaded correctly, what you want is [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) as on the `submit` event browser submits the form and the `handleLogin` function is not executed.

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$("#loginForm").on("submit",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   handleLogin()
});
```

Comment: @ undefined after replacing old code with your once still same page gets called. And If I print using console.log() before e.preventDefault() statement then also statement is not printed. Means control is not going inside that block.